# How can I add a wildcard to a variable to pass to "do shell script?"

Tags: bash, applescript

I have a directory on a remote server called `A00122-StupidLongNameThatIHaveToKeep`.
I have an AppleScript to copy files to the server using only the project number. Before it copies, I want to verify that the path is valid. To do this I thought I could send a command over SSH to verify the project exists and get the full name using `find`

```
set projectNumber to A00122
set projectPath to do shell script "ssh " & uName & "@server.com '( find /Volumes/HardDrive/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -name '" & projectNumber & "*' )'"
```

The expected shell command is:

```
`ssh username@server.com '( find /Volumes/HardDrive/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -name 'A00122*'`
```

Which should return 
`/Volumes/HardDrive/A00122-StupidLongNameThatIHaveToKeep`

But instead I get:
`no matches found: A00122*`

How can I add a wildcard to my variable and pass it to `do shell script`?

Comment: I'd assume that you have nested single quotes in there.

Comment: @Jetchisel where do you mean?

Comment: Ahh, applescript, sorry don't know about that but I just thought I saw a nested single quotes in your example.

Comment: Note that using string concatenation to generate code is, from a security perspective, a Really Bad Idea. The shell equivalent to SQL injection is "shell injection", and because it _always_ allows arbitrary operating system commands, it's arguably even worse. The safe way to run an arbitrary operating-system command from a non-shell language is via an `execve`-style interface that lets you pass an explicit argument list _as a list_, quoted per that native non-shell language's rules. (See `man execv` -- it's a C call, but pretty much any language worth its salt has some equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic complications here: first, the pieced you're building the `find` command out of are going to go through three different layers of parsing -- first by AppleScript, then by a local shell, and finally by a remote shell -- and each layer will parse, apply, *and remove* a layer of quotes and/or escapes. And second, quotes don't nest; it looks like you're trying to use a combination of single-quotes and parentheses to get an unexpanded wildcard through the two levels of shell parsing, and it just doesn't work that way.

Let's go through the three layers to see where things go off the tracks. Start with the AppleScript command:

```
set projectPath to do shell script "ssh " & uName & "@server.com '( find /Volumes/HardDrive/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -name '" & projectNumber & "*' )'"
```

AppleScript parses and removes the double-quotes (along with inserting variables), giving something like this:

```
ssh fred@server.com '( find /Volumes/HardDrive/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -name 'A00122*' )'
                     ^----------------------------------------------------^       ^--^
```

That's essentially what you said you wanted, but it's not going to do what you want, because (as I said) quotes don't nest. When the shell parses this, it's going to treat the sections I underlined as being in single-quotes, and the section between them -- which I think you intended to be inside two levels of quotes -- as being completely unquoted! Now, the fact that `A00122*` isn't in quotes doesn't matter at this point (unless you have some *really* weirdly named files on the local computer), but the problem is that *all* of those quotes are going to be removed before the command is sent to the remote shell. So what the remote shell receives is:

```
( find /Volumes/HardDrive/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -name A00122* )
```

Since the `A00122*` is not in quotes at this point, the remote shell will try to expand it into a list of matching files, which (apparently) fails, and the error message suggests that the remote shell is zsh, which complains about unmatched wildcards (by default). Also, note that the parentheses aren't doing anything useful here; I think they may've been intended to allow the quotes to nest, but that doesn't work.

So, suggestion 1: remove the parentheses and "inner" single-quotes and add an escape (which has to be doubled to get past AppleScript) for the wildcard:

```
set projectPath to do shell script "ssh " & uName & "@server.com 'find /Volumes/HardDrive/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -name " & projectNumber & "\\*'"
```

Suggestion 2: if you're only doing a depth-1 search, why not just let the shell expand the wildcard and `echo` the result:

```
set projectPath to do shell script "ssh " & uName & "@server.com 'echo " & projectNumber & "*'"
```

...and then check whether the result starts with "A00122-" (note that the dash is important here, since shells other than zsh will probably return "A00122*").

Comment: Suggest 2 is pretty smart, but Suggestion 1 works well so I'm going with that. Thank you for the very thorough explanation, it finally makes sense to me.